# What is this strange looking aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-identification, turboprop

[This website](https://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-twin-tail.htm) describes twin-tail aircraft. It has a photo of a strange-looking aircraft with a twin tail, and turboprop engines, resembling a C-130 Hercules.

[image]

There was no registration or tail number on the aircraft. I looked around at other images trying to find the name, but it did not feature the same aircraft. The aircraft looks fictitious.

Comment: The tail resembles an-225 so the logical thing is to check antonov wikipedia.

Comment: The An-22 is **much** larger than a Hercules.

Comment: @Peter, nevertheless Hercules managed to beat Antaeus ;)

Comment: "aircraft looks fictitious" almost always means former Soviet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is an Antonov [An-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-22) “Antei”.

Comment: It really kinda looks like the photo has had markings effaced for some reason that suited the posting site. Very unlikely an aircraft in a non-stealth paint scheme wouldn't have registrations, flags, any kind of marking. I do find that a reverse photo search includes https://www.icepop.com/largest-military-planes, on which there is a photo which but for the terrain features could be a flipped copy of this, with the markings present and the aircraft identified.

Comment: That's two related photos over the same terrain, with a few seconds between them and one flipped.

Comment: @CCTO: Yes nearly the same image ([comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTCcH.jpg)). Same shadows, and amazingly, nearly the same blade angular positions.